# How to Draw Polyline between two markers or coordinates on mapmyindia using React Native?

Tags: react-native, mapmyindia-api

How to draw poly line between two markers or coordinates in mappls-map-react-native. Please find the below sample code which is tried. I can't find any sample from in official doc.

```
"react-native": "0.72.7",
"mappls-map-react-native": "^1.0.6"

let route = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
          {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                        [
                             19.2052853,
                             72.8708257
                        ],
                        [
                             12.991463333333334,
                             77.70299666666666
                        ]
                ]
                }
          }
        ]
  }
<MapplsGL.MapView
      style={{flex: 1}}
      zoomEnabled={true}
      onPress={event => console.log('event', event)}>
      <MapplsGL.Camera
       ref={c  => (this.camera = c)}
          zoomLevel={13}
          animationMode="easeTo"
          centerCoordinate={[long, lat]}
      />
      <MapplsGL.ShapeSource id='line1' shape={route}>
             <MapplsGL.LineLayer id='linelayer1' style={{lineColor:'#ff0000'}} />
     </MapplsGL.ShapeSource>
     <MapplsGL.UserLocation visible={true}></MapplsGL.UserLocation>
</MapplsGL.MapView>
```